# Migrating from WSO2 Enterprise Integrator to Micro Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

What are the risks of migrating from WSO2 Enterprise Integrator to Micro Integrator ?
According to the documentation, a support ticket should be opened for help. But no documentation lists the risks / challenges of similar migration.

What about the API Manager, is the shipped MI inside the AM works the same as having an external MI?
In the future, will AM replace MI ? or will they remain independent separate products? (as according to the AM latest version, the MI is now shipped inside the AM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations always involve risks but should be mitigated through testing. The risk depends on the current integrations you have.

1. If you have customizations that highly depend on Core components you may have to update them.
2. Some of the connectors may not be supported in MI.
3. The DB-backed registry which was in EI was removed in MI and now it has a file-system-based registry, so if you relied on the registry make sure everything works as expected.
4. If you are using MSMPs, Inbound Endpoints, and Tasks with cluster coordination, Hazlecast-based clustering was removed in MI and a new DB-backed clustering model was implemented.
5. If you heavily relied on the EI's Management Console. It has been rewritten as MI Dashboard which has limited functionality.

The good part is both EI and MI use the same synapse runtime, so you will not have to do many changes to your integrations when migrating. MI runs as a separate runtime in the latest APIM 4.2 distribution, they just combined both APIM and MI into a single distribution which has two runtimes within.

As per [this](https://wso2.com/products/support-matrix/) MI 4.2 will be supported through Mar 22, 2026. And I believe that eventually it will e replaced by something like [Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/). Migrating to Barrina will not be an easy task as you will have to rewrite everything.